# Can you help me to find the order of the model from the acf and pacf plots?

Tags: time-series

[image][image]
Please help me to find the order of the model
time series

Answer (score 0):

Let us review the assumptions that are made when it is safe to visually or computationally map the sample acf and pacf to a useful arima model. Firstly there must be no deterministic structure latent in your data i.e. no pulses , no step/level shifts , no seasonal pulses and no time trends (often called Deterministic Trends) . Secondly the parameters of the arima model must be invariant over time yielding an error process that has constant variance.

(0,1,0)(0,1,0)13 would be my guess given the caveats above BUT only the data knows for sure.

Why don't you post your data so you can get a precise answer.